# Which public key algorithm should I use for encrypting small chunk of bytes?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Background story:
I'm trying to write my own logging library. It's for hobby purposes. There's one must for me: **logged data must be encrypted asymmetrically**. The log messages are always directly written into the file, no caching occurs, no waiting for any queue.

This means I'll have to encrypt bunch of small chunks of messages. Even though the bottleneck is probably going to be the lack of caching & IO operations, I'd like to choose the encryption algorithm wisely.

Summary:

- I have to encrypt numerous of small (<200 bytes) of data
- Algorithm MUST be asymmetric, I'd like to encrypt with the public key and the only be able to decrypt it with my very own private key

What algorithm do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not going to give recommendations nor will I give you the standard lecture about hybrid encryption, but I will tell what will work. If you use RSA 2048 keys with RSA encryption and OAEPWithSHA256 padding then you can encrypt messages up to 190 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.

Comment: If you could explain the reason for stressing on Asymmetric encryption, it would be more reasonable to answer. As a rule of thumb, you are not supposed to encrypt large amounts of data using Asymmetric keys as they are slower and are meant for a different purpose. 
In terms of security, you can arrive at the same level of security with Asymmetric and Symmetric methods. 
Since the security is out of the way, we can focus on speed, Symmetric encryption is faster with hardware acceleration almost ubiquitous.
If there is a different motivation, it would help in answering towards what you need.

Comment: @pikaynu My reason is only that the encrypted data - according to my knowledge - is only decryptable if someone has full access to the currently running process. If the data had been encrypted, then it's mathematically nearly impossible for any attacker to decrypt the log files. Is it true?

Comment: @Prune Thank you for your suggestion, the posting guide told me that even if I might not post to the right place, the mods will help me to find the best suiting. I wasn't sure where such questions should take place.

Comment: @Prune I'm not sure what you're trying to convey with this canned comment, but I don't think it's effective. I suspect you're trying to say “SO is not for do-this-coding-for-me”, but that's not quite what “SO is not a coding resource” means. Of course it's a resource _about_ coding. And it's a resource on software design as well. And you can do research on it, as in, look for information on it. And you can learn from it, so it's a tutorial resource. Whatever it is you have against this question, which looks perfectly fine for SO to me, you should *explain* it, rather than use a canned comment.

Comment: Also see [tamper evident logging](http://tamperevident.cs.rice.edu/Logging.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're interpreting “logged data must be encrypted asymmetrically” literally as a low-level requirement. “Logged data must be encrypted asymmetrically” is not a security requirement, it's an implementation approach. It's a bad implementation approach, because it requires you to design your own cryptographic protocol (you can use standard primitives, but only in a non-standard way), and it would have annoying limitations.

A much more reasonable requirement is “the machine that produces the logs must not be able to decrypt them”. This is a security requirement: it is a requirement on an asset (the logs) concerning its security (specifically their confidentiality).

The way to implement this security requirement is indeed to use asymmetric encryption. But you don't take an asymmetric encryption primitive and pass the logs as input to that. Rather, you use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem): generate a symmetric key, encrypt the logs with that, encrypt the symmetric key with the asymmetric key, and erase the symmetric key.

The best way to do this is to use a library that does it well. The [`crypto_box`](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html), [`crypto_box_easy`](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption) and [`crypto_box_seal`](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes) functions of [NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/) or [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) are the gold standards here. You pass the public key for encryption, the message to sign, and you get an encrypted “box” out which can only be decrypted with the private key. `crypto_box_easy` and `crypto_box` also take your own private key as an argument, to sign the logs, which you might not want in your toy example but is usually important in the real world. `crypto_box_easy` and `crypto_box` also take a nonce as argument; this can be any value that can be public but that you must not use twice, for example a random string of `crypto_box_NONCEBYTES` bytes.

If you don't want to use crypto_box, for example because you want to learn how it's done under the hood, you have to assemble the parts manually, using your chosen low-level cryptographic library. The flow is different depending on which flavor of asymmetric encryption you use. With a key establishment method such as ECIES:

1. Generate a random one-time private key *y*.
2. Calculate the corresponding public value *g<sup>y</sup>*.
3. Using the recipient's public key *g<sup>x</sup>*, calculate the shared secret *g<sup>xy</sup>*.
4. Apply a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) such as [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) to deterministically generate a secret symmetric key, for example an AES key or a Chacha20_Poly1305 key.
5. Use the secret symmetric key to encrypt the log message, for example using AES-GCM or Chacha20_Poly1305.
6. Optionally, hash the log message and sign it with your public key.
7. Wipe the one-time private key, the shared secret, the secret symmetric key, the plaintext log, and any other intermediate value from memory.
8. Send the ciphertext, the public value*g<sup>y</sup>* and optionally the signature.

With a key encryption method such as RSA-OAEP:

1. Generate a random one-time secret key, for example an AES key or a Chacha20_Poly1305 key.
2. Use the secret symmetric key to encrypt the log message, for example using AES-GCM or Chacha20_Poly1305.
3. Optionally, hash the log message and sign it with your public key.
4. Encrypt the symmetric key using the recipient's public key.
5. Wipe the one-time secret key, the plaintext log, and any other intermediate value from memory.
6. Send the ciphertext, the public value*g<sup>y</sup>* and optionally the signature.

Doing the steps manually may have a performance benefit if you decide that it's ok to encrypt multiple log messages with the same symmetric key. This has a performance benefit, because asymmetric operations are slower than symmetric operations. There is no long-term security drawback to doing this. The only security drawback is a short-term one: all logs from the current symmetric key can still be decrypted. If you decide, for example, that it's ok if an attacker who breaches your system can read the last minute's logs, then you can renew the symmetric key every minute.

Comment: This is a very details and helpful answer. Thank you for your time! Now I see why I shouldn't have stated a solution method as an initial requirement.